# Is Uncomplicated FireWall (ufw) a service?

Tags: firewall, ufw

I am currently studying **iptables** and **ufw** on Ubuntu server. While playing with them I came across an ambiguity about the true nature of the **ufw**.

Here is the problem:

- When I run `sudo ufw status` in terminal, the output is `Status: inactive`.
- But when I run `sudo service ufw status` the output is `ufw start/running`.

Also **ufw** does not appear in the services list when I run `service --status-all`.

So my questions are:

1. Is **ufw** a service?

   - If **yes**, why it does not appear in the *services* list?
   - If **no**, why the terminal answers when I ask about it's *status* as a *service*?
2. What is the difference between `sudo ufw status` and `sudo service ufw status`? And why I get different outputs for them?

Comment: first of all, which version is this?

Comment: @AizuddinZali Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64)

Comment: ok thats weird when you see `ufw status` and `service ufw status` not tally. Try to `service ufw restart`. Sometime this caused by pid file went missing.

Comment: **@AizuddinZali** I did perform the `service ufw restart` and it worked. Now I get the same result for both of the commands as: `ufw start/running`. Does this mean that they are identical commands?

Comment: no they are not, `service` is part of init that call `ufw` program. While `ufw` is the program itself.

Comment: **@AizuddinZali** So if I'm right, **ufw is not a service**. But when it's running system sees it as a service. right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30402/discussion-between-vardumper-and-aizuddin-zali).

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 the ufw daemon is run via `upstart` rather than using a traditional Sys V type init script. You should be able to see its status using `sudo initctl status ufw` in place of `sudo service ufw status`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ufw` is an uncomplicated configuration tool for firewalls.  It is designed to be usable by people who have no experience with firewalls or want an uncomplicated way to modify the underlying `iptables` and `netfilter` rulesets.

For example:

**ufw allow all port 22 traffic (UDP and TCP)**:

```
ufw allow 22
```

**iptables allow port 22 traffic (UDP and TCP):**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comparatively, `ufw` permits users to modify the basic firewall needs with limited knowledge of `iptables` or such.

It in and of itself only modifies `iptables` / `netfilter` rules when 'enabled'.  It does not run as its own process, in that sense, because the rules it applies are updated on the fly; I am fairly certain it doesn't continue to 'run'.

The only way I would consider `ufw` to be a service is in that, at boot time, it may be able to restore whatever rules are defined in it.  However, `iptables-persistent` does the same thing, and is not really a service, therefore I do not consider `ufw` a service, as such, as to determine if `ufw` (that is, the actual ***firewall rules***) are being enforced is with `ufw status`.

[As per the Community Help Documentation on `ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW), it says nothing about `ufw` being a service, which seems to support this.

And through testing, I have confirmed that `ufw` is just a less complicated way to 'configure' firewall rules - the real magic of `ufw` is that it sets up `iptables` / `netfilter` rules which you can then see with `iptables -L` when `ufw` is enabled.

Comment: This chosen answer says that ufw is not a service, but there's a comment and another answer that says it is. I want to believe that ufw is effectively only a config editor, but this level of confusion gives me doubt.

Comment: ... and prompted my own question at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090122/ufw-what-exactly-is-it

Comment: @gwideman It in and of itself is "not a service" - it as a service is just the "on boot" loading of the ruleset.  It's still *not* a 'service' in the traditional sense of a service or daemon that always runs, it just applies rules to the underlying netfilter/iptables which is always on and can't be turned off.

Comment: On investigating further, your comment seems to make almost the right distinction.  ufw does seem to count as a service, in that 'service ufw status' shows it (ufw.service). But that listing reports 'loaded active exited', which seems to mean that its executable ran, did whatever it was configured to do (which could be nothing if its config doesn't say enabled), and then exited.  So it's not listed in 'ps aux' as having a running process, as you noted.

Answer (score 3):

- As far as the Ubuntu documentation, `ufw` is an application that is running as a system service.
- No.2 question is simple....

  The two mentioned commands are quite different:

  - `ufw status` shows only if the firewall filtering is active, to enable it type `sudo ufw enable`.
  - `service ufw status` shows only if the service itself is operating.

Comment: Well, that's neat and tidy :-) but what does it mean for the 'ufw status' to be inactive, and the 'service ufw status' to be active (also exited)?  You say this means the service is "operating" -- but in what sense of operating? It has no running process, and it provided no rules to iptables/netfilter. I acknowledge that service ufw status _says_ it's active, which must mean something, but what?