# UFW: what exactly is it?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

What is UFW? You would think this is an easy question, but the more sources I read, the less clear it gets.

The acronym spells out to Uncomplicated FireWall, as though ufw actually implements a firewall itself. And indeed in many places it is referred to as a firewall per se, such as in [this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-firewall-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

[The Ubuntu help wiki page on UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) says that UFW is a configuration tool for iptables. (In turn, [the help wiki page on firewalls](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firewall) says that iptables is the database of firewall rules, and that it is also the actual firewall, as though a database is a firewall, which is obviously false. And of course 'iptables' is also the name of a program.)

If ufw is a configuration tool, then we might expect it to be a program that you run to configure something, and once done, you quit with the config having been established.  That's the position of this question's accepted answer: [Is Uncomplicated FireWall (ufw) a service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686955/is-uncomplicated-firewall-ufw-a-service/737915#737915)

But other answers on that question disagree -- no, it's a service. And indeed on my 18.04 machine, I see that ufw is running as a service! Why the heck does a configuration tool run as a service?!

Further, `systemctl list-units --all --type=service` shows `ufw.service` is `loaded and active` (and also `exited`?!) yet `ufw status` shows `inactive`.

So what does ufw status = inactive mean?

1. That "the firewall" (whatever that is) is inactive?  That's what [the ufw man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/ufw.8.html) doc for 'status' would suggest.
2. Or does it mean that the rules configured in ufw are inactive (but others configured in iptables are active)?
3. Or does it mean that ufw started on bootup, instated its rules into ipconfig (or wherever they go) so that they are now in effect, and now ufw has nothing to do so it's inactive?

Of particular interest:  I want to follow some instructions that require issuing some iptables commands, but am concerned that they will conflict with, or be overwritten by, the ufw apparatus.

Comment: iptables is the firewall. It also holds the rules, because it obviously needs to, but calling it a ‘database’ is stretching it a bit as kernel provides no persistency; loading them at boot time has to be taken care of by some tool like ufw.

Comment: @JanHudec I see some people talk about iptables as though it's the firewall, but so far as I can tell, netfilter provides the firewall functionality, while iptables provides the date for netfilter.  I like your point that iptables only holds data in memory, and thus "database" is also misleading.

Comment: I would personally consider netfilter to be part of iptables, but I might be wrong in this fine point.

Comment: Zanna edited my question to tidy things like URLs (thanks!), but has substituted "UFW" for all instances of "ufw". I now believe that lowercase is the proper case (as shown in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/ufw.8.html and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall, but I'm not interested in an edit war on this. Zanna please revert to lower case if you buy my evidence.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ufw is a front-end for netfilter/iptables, the Linux mechanism for routing and filtering internet traffic.

ufw is completely optional and it's possible to create firewall and routing tables directly using the iptables commands.  Some people prefer the syntax of ufw, which is supposed to make it a bit easier.

ufw itself is not the firewall, it's a tool for setting the configuration of netfilter/iptables.  It is registered as a service because it needs to be run every time your machine starts up.  I don't believe it stays resident in memory after it has done this configuration.  "restarting" the service simply re-runs its scripts.  It is not unusual for things in Linux distributions to be registered as services even though they are merely scripts that run at boot or shutdown without staying resident in between.

If you use ufw you can't set your own iptables rules using your own scripts, as they will be overwritten when ufw sets its own.  This also means that ufw can conflict with other tools that set firewall rules.

If `sudo ufw status` returns "inactive", it means ufw has been disabled (and won't, for example, re-apply any rules at startup).  You need to ensure ufw is enabled with `sudo ufw enable`, though you also need to configure rules for this to have meaning.  If you are sure you have enabled ufw but it returns "inactive" there could be some other issue.

Note that "starting" the service doesn't enable ufw, it just activates the start-up script.  If ufw is disabled when the start-up script runs it won't do anything.

You can tell if your firewall rules have been applied at any given time using iptables directly:

```
sudo iptables -L
sudo ip6tables -L
```

Comment: Note: I personally don't use ufw, I use a package called netfilter-persistent which allows you to write up native iptables rules into a file and have them re-applied at boot.  At boot, it essentially does what ufw does: runs a start script which applies the configuration.  The difference is it's not translating from its own simplified syntax, it's merely sending the iptables commands directly to iptables.

Comment: Lots of good stuff there. Thanks. On this: "If you use ufw you can't set your own iptables rules using your own scripts, as they will be overwritten when ufw sets its own."  Does ufw actively delete all existing iptables rules?  Or are you just saying with ufw in the picture, you can't rely on iptables commands/rules taking effect because they _might_ get overwritten by ufw?

Comment: Also to thomas: "netfilter-persistent" > does that relate to iptables-persistent?

Comment: Yes that's what it used to be called. If your Ubuntu version has both, then the iptables-persistent package will probably just be a transitional package to give people from older versions an upgrade path.

Comment: "Does ufw actively delete all existing iptables rules?" Yes, I am pretty sure it does, because it would start by flushing all the existing rules then adding its own. If you have two different things setting iptables rules then they'll be destroying each others' rules when they run. Just like with resolve.conf and things like that. You can only pick one to manage your rules at a time. You're buying into a system

Comment: Wait... how does resolv.conf fit into this?

Comment: Sorry if I confused you mentioning resolv.conf, I was just using as an example of another piece of configuration in Ubuntu which might be controlled by some other service overriding any changes you make directly.  It's not connected.

Comment: @gwideman Regarding `If you use ufw you can't set your own iptables rules` I solved this issue by running my script, then enabling `ufw` and setting some rules there and after I am done I used `iptables-persistant` to save that whole thing. It looks okay but I am also posting this here for people to criticize!

Comment: @Ben assuming you turned off ufw after doing that, that approach sounds fine, but it means that your rules are stored as raw iptables rules in /etc/iptables/ now anyway - so if you want to further modify them you may as well bypass ufw and just edit the iptables rules there.

Comment: @thomasrutter Thanks, I actually left it turned on as I was not aware of the way it works. `iptables -L -v` showed a lot of entries for my `ufw` then. Maybe it worked because `ufw` just adds rules in my case.